# Error 1061 C# does not contain a definition for and no ..first argument of type could be found

Tags: c#, uwp

I have two errors, please explain what is the reason that is wrong, and how to fix thank you. Project write in Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app.
    Method that I'm trying to call:

```
private void AddButton_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Getting Data From UI

        u.first_name = first_name.ToString();
        u.last_name = last_name.ToString();
        u.email = email.ToString();
        u.username = username.ToString();
        u.password = password.ToString();
        u.address = address.ToString();
        u.gender = gender.ToString();
        u.user_type = user_type.ToString();
        u.added_date = DateTime.Now;
        u.added_by = 1;

        //Inserting Data info Database
        bool success = dal.Insert(u);
        //If the data is successfully inserted then the value of succesess
        if(success==true)
        {
            //data Successfully inserted
            Msgbox.Show("User successfully created.");
            clear();
        }
        else
        {
            Msgbox.Show("Failed to add new user");
        }
        //Refreshing Data View
        DataTable dt = dal.Select();
        dgvUsers.DataContext = dt;

    }
```

XAML code

```
<Pivot>
            <Pivot.RightHeader >
                <CommandBar OverflowButtonVisibility="Collapsed" Background="Transparent" >
                    <AppBarButton x:Name="btn1" Icon="Add" Click="AddButton_Click"/>
                    <AppBarSeparator/>
                    <AppBarButton x:Name="btn2" Icon="Delete" Click="DeleteButton_Click"/>
                    <AppBarSeparator/>
                </CommandBar>
            </Pivot.RightHeader>
        </Pivot>
```

Comment: Which line of the code gives error?

Comment: Error CS1061 'UserPage' does not contain a definition for 'AddButton_Click' and no accessible extension method 'AddButton_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'UserPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I think its  // UserPage.xaml line 50
                {
                    this.btn2 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.AppBarButton)(target);
                    ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.AppBarButton)this.btn2).Click += this.DeleteButton_Click;
                }

Comment: You have method `AddButton_ClickAsync` but you have `Click="AddButton_Click"` in xaml. So either you change the name of the method to `AddButton_Click"` or change to `Click="AddButton_ClickAsync"` in Xaml code.

Comment: funny, I'm sorry inconsiderate :)

Answer (score 0):

Your issues lies with the method names. Look at following lines.

```
<AppBarButton x:Name="btn1" Icon="Add" Click="AddButton_Click"/>
```

and

```
private void AddButton_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

In your Xaml, you are calling a method named "AddButton_Click" on Click event, but the method is actually named "AddButton_ClickAsync". You need to change with either so that both are same.

The second error, would be in following line.

```
<AppBarButton x:Name="btn2" Icon="Delete" Click="DeleteButton_Click"/>
```

You do not have a definition of DeleteButton_Click, or atleast you haven't shared it. So most likely the second error would be in this line.

PS: Can't say for sure unless whole code is shared, but mostly likely areas are these.